# Google PageSpeed Insight CSS Javascript "above the fold" issue using CDN

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-pagespeed

I tried to implement **CDN** resources with **local fallback** support for my webpage.
But now I can't get rid of render-blocking JavaScript and CSS CDN resources for **jquery** and **Bootstrap** in the "above-the-fold" content.

I tried to stick to **Googles Guidelines** but it didn't resolve my problem:

- [Remove Render-Blocking JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS)
- [Optimize CSS Delivery](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery#example)

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">...</div>
  <!-- jQuery CDN -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery local fallback -->
  <script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="./assets/scripts/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"><\/script>')
  </script>
  <!-- Bootstrap JS CDN -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js</script>
  <!-- Bootstrap JS local fallback -->
  <script>if(typeof($.fn.modal) === 'undefined') {document.write('<script src="./assets/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"><\/script>')}</script>
   <!-- Bootstrap CSS local fallback -->
   <div id="bootstrapCssTest " class="hide "></div>
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
         if ($('#bootstrapCssTest').is(':visible') === true) {
              $("head ").append('<link rel="stylesheet " href="./assets/styles/bootstrap.min.css">');
         }
      });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet " href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css ">
```

**UPDATE:** I tried to use the "async/defer" attribute for loading my .js CDN scripts. But it didn't work as my local fallback script gives me **"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"** error because they are executed before jquery async loading had been finished.

Comment: place them just before the closing body tag (`</body>`) at the very bottom of your page. That'll fix your problem. No async needed then. And never outside the `</html>`. Btw; css can be placed in the head, only javascript should be placed at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Script are already before closing body tag. Moved the css into the head, but still getting the same Pagespeed issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using jQuery library include footer section and below custom code start jquery code
2. 40% CSS code in above-the-fold content (head section using internal stylesheet ) `<style type="text/css">...</style>`

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">...</div>
  <div id="bootstrapCssTest" class="hide"></div>
  <!-- jQuery CDN -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery local fallback -->
  <script src="../scripts/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap JS CDN -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
  <!-- Bootstrap JS local fallback -->
  <script src="../scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS local fallback -->
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      if ($('#bootstrapCssTest').is(':visible') === true) {
        $("head ").append('<link rel="stylesheet " href="./assets/styles/bootstrap.min.css">');
      }
    });
  </script>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet " href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css ">
</body>
</html>
```